# PDE minimisation with $L^{1}$ function

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Exercise from Brezis:

*Let $I=(0,1)$ and fix a constant $k>0$. Given $f\in L^{1}(I)$ prove that there exists a unique $u\in H_{0}^{1}(I)$ satisfying
\begin{align}
\int_{I}u'v'+k\int_{I}uv=\int_{I}fv\quad\forall v\in H_{0}^{1}(I).
\end{align}*

I have shown that the bilinear form,
\begin{align}
a(u,v)=\int_{I}u'v'+k\int_{I}uv,
\end{align}
is continuous, coercive and symmetric. However, I do not know how to deal with $f\in L^{1}(I)$. How can I find a functional $\varphi\in (H_{0}^{1}(I))^{*}$ such that there is a unique $f\in L^{2}(I)\subset H^{-1}(I)$ giving the integral representation,
\begin{align}
\langle\varphi,v\rangle=\int_{I}fv\quad\forall v\in H^{1}_{0}(I)?
\end{align}

Comment: You do not need to *find* $\varphi$, it is already there. You have that it satisfies the requirements of the theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you define
$$\phi(v):= \int_I fv\ dx.$$
Second, you have to verify that $\phi$ is defined on $H^1_0(I)$, linear, and bounded.
Linearity is obvious. For well-definedness and boundedness, you might check for suitable embedding theorems (and H\"older inequality).